# Windows on top pygetwindow

Tags: python

```
import pygetwindow as gw
import time


while True:
    try:
       gw.getWindowsWithTitle('onTopTest')[0].activate()
    except:
       NULL=0

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I have a folder named "onTopTest" that I always want on top. The Problem is that I have to manually click (focus) the "C:\Windows\py.exe" Terminal window to get it do it's job.

Comment: Windows doesn't allow windows to bring themselves to the top.